# How to find dependency causing "Sirupsen/logrus" vs. "sirupsen/logrus" unexpected module path error?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to convert https://github.com/appscode/voyager from glide to go mod.

I am getting an error like below:

```
go: github.com/Sirupsen/logrus@v1.4.1: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
go: error loading module requirements
```

How do I find out the source of this old Sirupsen module?

Comment: Have you tried using `go mod why`? Although if you can't parse `go.mod`, I'm not sure what you can do other than remove the offending module path. (also make sure you're using the latest go release to generate `go.mod`, and run `go mod tidy`)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/mJcpYYim3-w

Comment: "How do I find out the source of this old Sirupsen module?" - it's not old, it's still actively maintained, and the source is exactly where the import path indicates: github.com/sirupsen/logrus

Comment: Yes, 1.4.1 was _long_ after the rename, there should be no reason to have the `Sirupsen` path in your code.

Answer (score 9):

> How do I find out the source of this old Sirupsen module?

Use the Go 1.13 beta (`go get golang.org/dl/go1.13beta1 && go1.13beta1 download`) or even better, try the latest Go on tip / master (`go get golang.org/dl/gotip && gotip download`).

Go 1.13 has improved error messages in general. It should help in your case, including most likely showing the import chain leading up to the error.

For example:

```
$ gotip build .
go: example.com/temp/mod imports
        github.com/docker/libcompose/docker imports
        github.com/Sirupsen/logrus: github.com/Sirupsen/logrus@v1.4.2: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: github.com/Sirupsen/logrus
                but was required as: github.com/sirupsen/logrus
```

In that example, you can see that `docker/libcompose/docker` is importing the old and now incorrect uppercase version of `Sirupsen/logrus`.

The most common reason people see a `Sirupsen/logrus` vs. `sirupsen/logrus` case mismatch is when importing `github.com/docker/docker` or one of the other docker repos. Importing docker repos is a bit confusing with modules, including because:

- The `docker/docker` repo does not follow semver.
- There is a very old `v1.13.1` semver tag on the `docker/docker` repo.

  - Even though it is a couple years old, it is still the "latest" semver tag on that repo, and hence that old version is picked by default by the `go` command if you don't ask for a more specific version.
  - That old `docker/docker` version imports the old and not incorrect uppercase `Sirupsen/logrus`, which can then trigger the error reported in the question above.
- The docker client package has had breaking changes after v1.13.1.
- There is generally confusion about `docker/docker` vs. `docker/engine` repositories, and about what import paths to use.
- The docker repos do not have `go.mod` files.

For the `docker/docker` repo, the import path remains `github.com/docker/docker`, but it needs to come from `github.com/docker/engine`, so the recommended approach is often for a docker importer to do `import "github.com/docker/docker"` and edit their `go.mod` to something like this:

```
require (
    github.com/docker/docker v1.13.1
)

replace github.com/docker/docker => github.com/docker/engine <tag-or-commit-hash>
```

Docker issue [#39302](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39302) tracks trying to document how to import docker repos when using modules.

Comment: I tried to do this with docker/distribution but get this: `replace github.com/distribution/distribution: version "v2.7.1" invalid: should be v0 or v1, not v2`